# Can two iPhones share same backup space on cloud?

Tags: icloud

I have an iPhone 6+ and my girlfriend an iPhone 6. Can I backup her phone on my iCloud account? I have 200 gigs of space and would like to share backup space. Her phone is constantly displaying a message that her iPhone does not have sufficient space for backups.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, you can backup as many devices as you have the ability to sign in to and have space for the backups in your iCloud, **but** iCloud Backup can only back up to the main iCloud account on a device.

Comment: 2 phones, one account… but would that work for 2 accounts?

Comment: from the OP - "Can I backup her phone on my iCloud account?" I'd have said, not unless they both use the same account - which isn't clearly explained in the post, but makes me feel it's 2 accounts, not one.

Comment: Cool - covers all the bases now. Thanks for your edit. Feel free to clear these comments if you think they're no longer required.